# Using sed - how to replace truncated values with separate values within a line?

Tags: linux, sed

Example log data:

```
SVCELPTIME=19,FAILPT=9580-8582,MICROSERVICE=YES
SVCELPTIME=411,FAILPT=9210-80129210-8686,MICROSERVICE=YES
REFNO=JAJRJZ,TXNREFNO=63165718100281723,SVCELPTIME=21,FAILPT=9210-80129210-86519210-8651,CD=PT
```

A `FAILPT` is defined as "4 digits-4 digits". Such as `9580-8582`.
The issue I have is on some lines, multiple `FAILPT`'s are truncated into the first. Such as: `9580-85819580-85829580-8583`, 
and I need them each treated as a separate key value pair.

Using sed:

```
echo FAILPT=9210-80129210-86519230-8012 | sed 's/FAILPT=//; s/.\{4\}\|.\{4\}-.\{4\}/FAILPT=&,/g; s/,$//'
```

This produces:
`FAILPT=9210-8012,FAILPT=9210-8651,FAILPT=9230-8012`  <-exactly what i need.

But when i try to apply the logfile, It clobbers everything.

Such as (using the example line):

```
FAILPT=SVCE,FAILPT=LPTI,FAILPT=ME=1,FAILPT=9,95,FAILPT=80-8,FAILPT=582,,FAILPT=MICR,FAILPT=OSER,FAILPT=VICE,FAILPT==YES
FAILPT=SVCE,FAILPT=LPTI,FAILPT=ME=4,FAILPT=11,9,FAILPT=210-,FAILPT=8012,FAILPT=9210-8686,FAILPT=,MIC,FAILPT=ROSE,FAILPT=RVIC,FAILPT=E=YE,S
FAILPT=REFN,FAILPT=O=JA,FAILPT=JRJZ,FAILPT=,TXN,FAILPT=REFN,FAILPT=O=63,FAILPT=1657,FAILPT=1810,FAILPT=0281,FAILPT=723,,FAILPT=SVCE,FAILPT=LPTI,FAILPT=ME=2,FAILPT=1,92,FAILPT=10-8,FAILPT=0129,FAILPT=210-,FAILPT=8651,FAILPT=9210-8651,FAILPT=,CD=,PT
```

How can I replace/append ONLY the `FAILPT=` values and not touch the rest of the line?

Comment: I forgot to mention that a FAILPT can also be  4 digits without a dash (thus the "OR" statement in the sed line. But a 4 digit FAILPT will never be followed by a 4-4 patten. It's one type or the other.

Comment: Hi Tee Lin, please add the requirement to your question!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question with the comment. I only need to look for 4-4 patterns or multiples of them. it was the OR clause that was messing things up.

```
sed '/FAILPT=*,/p; s/FAILPT=//; s/.\{4\}-.\{4\}/FAILPT=&,/g; s/,,/,/'
```